# SASL password normalization

Tags: passwords, sasl, unicode-normalization

there is very simple question - can you normalize for me some password, because I can't understand how it works? So, there is password: "IDoMdGuFE9S0", how it looks in "normalized" view? There are only alphanumeric ascii characters. Does result and original be equal?

PS: Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming with "normalized" you mean [SASLpreped](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4013). In the case of "IDoMdGuFE9S0", the output is the same as the input (it is fully ASCII, with no control sequences or `U+00AD`).

If you're writing an application that uses SASL, you should find a library to do this for you.

Comment: Yes, thats it! I just want understand what to do with absolutely usual ascii characters, because I not found phrase in rfc "lets leave that chars how it looks" and you remove that whitespace, thank you!